# Can PostgreSQL be configured so that occasional mass updates can run super-fast?

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, bulkupdate

I have setup a PostgreSQL test environment which is required to contain the same amount of data (number of rows) as the production database, and be configured mostly production-like to simulate the same performance for normal transactions.

However, it being a test environment, occasionally has to have some unique, experimental, temporary, or ad-hoc changes applied. For instance, adding or removing some indexes before a performance test, recalculating the value of a column to replicate test conditions, dumping and reimporting whole tables, etc.

Is there a way to temporarily suspend data integrity guarantees in order to perform such types of mass update as fast as possible?

For example, in MySQL you can set over-sized write buffers, disable transaction logging, and suspend disk flushes on transaction commit. Is there something similar in pgsql?

The deployment environment is AWS EC2.

Comment: Maybe also build indices concurrently after inserting the bulk data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/populate.html) has a chapter dedicated to initial loading of a database.

There are some safe options you can change to make things faster:

- increasing [max_wal_size](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-MAX-WAL-SIZE)
- increasing [checkpoint_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-CHECKPOINT-TIMEOUT)
- [wal_level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-WAL-LEVEL) to `minimal`
- [wal_log_hints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-WAL-LOG-HINTS) to `off`
- [synchronous_commit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-COMMIT) to `off`

Then there are some rather unsafe options to make things faster. Unsafe meaning: **you can lose all your data** if the server crashes - so use at your own risk!

- [full_page_writes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-FULL-PAGE-WRITES) to `off`
- [fsync](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-FSYNC) to `off`

Again: by changing the two settings above, you risk **losing all your data**.

To disable WAL you could also set all tables to `unlogged`

Answer (score 2):

You can disable WAL logging with `ALTER TABLE ... SET UNLOGGED`, but be aware that the reverse operation will dump the whole table to WAL.

If that is not feasible, you can boost performance by setting `max_wal_size` hugh so that you get fewer checkpoints.

WAL flushing is disabled by setting `fsync = off`.

Be aware that the first and third measure will wreck your database in the event of a crash.